# Sum of column values based on other columns in R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R,trying to get sum of column based on other columns .my data frame is like below

```
YEAR EventID LOSS
    1     554  334740
    1     415  149816
    1     207  199446
    2     961  527042
    3     614  188199
    4     968   87044
    4     650   75377
    4     341  424678
    4     397  210730
    5     610  368068
```

Here my condition is , I need the sum of HIGHEST loss by each year.

loss numbers of : EVENTID 554 from YEAR 1,EVENTID 961 from YEAR 2, EVENTID 341 from 4, EVENTID 610 from YEAR 5.

Comment: This kind of thing is really easy with dplyr package. There are lots of tutorials available. Here is one, for example: [http://www.sharpsightlabs.com/dplyr-intro-data-manipulation-with-r/](http://www.sharpsightlabs.com/dplyr-intro-data-manipulation-with-r/)

Comment: You have to edit your post: EventID 968 is not the highest one in year 4.

Comment: `sum(tapply(df$LOSS, df$YEAR, max))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy one with `dplyr`:

```
d %>%
   group_by(YEAR) %>%
   summarize(EventID = EventID[1],
             max_loss = max(LOSS))
```

You can also have multiple occurrences of events with the same max loss, then you would need to merge back to original dataset and filter:

```
d %>%
   group_by(YEAR) %>%
   summarize(max_loss = max(LOSS)) %>%
   left_join(d, .) %>%
   filter(LOSS == max_loss)
```

Answer (score 1):

My preference goes to `sqldf` for this sort of tasks:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from mydata 
       group by YEAR
       having LOSS=max(LOSS);")
```

**Results**

```
##  YEAR EventID   LOSS
##     1     554 334740
##     2     961 527042
##     3     614 188199
##     4     341 424678
##     5     610 368068
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(unique(ave(df$LOSS, df$YEAR, FUN = max)))
```

Output:

```
[1] 1842727
```